# Chrome opens gibberish

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am struggling with one demo site.
I have uploaded it in a sub directory in the apache web server. Trough firefox it works, but Chrome and IE
Shows gibberis symbols (�[�n�8�=�;p�Eݠ��K���E�M��.....)

I assume that the issue is somewhere in the .htaccess file, however I am not quite familiar with the syntax and tried few things but didn't work.

Could you please take a look.
Any advice is appreciated.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite public elements path
RewriteRule ^(img|css|js|flags|libs)\/(.*)$ public/$1/$2

# Bootstrap
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(gif|png|jpg|ico|swf|txt|html|(min\.)?css|(min\.)?js|mp4|php|eot|woff2|woff|ttf|svg|xml)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new_deploy/index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: can you add the offending PHP script and give an example of the url parameter?

Comment: That looks like either a problem with character encoding, or content transfer encoding. Nothing in the .htaccess you have shown influences either of those directly though.

Comment: I also would take a look at character encoding. But unlike @CBroe I would take a closer look at the first line in your configuration file: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` ... _Is your content actually encoded in UTF-8_ ? Because if not then this certainly might explain the issue...